# Java Prepared Statement syntax to connect hive server for describing table

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, prepared-statement, describe

trying to establish connection to hive and describe a table.

```
enter code here
    String queryTable= "dummydb.dummy_table";
    String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //connect hive server (no issue in that)
    String hiveUrl = PropertyLoader.getInstance("staging").getDruidHive();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(hiveUrl, "hadoop", "");

    ##Working code is below:
         String sql = "describe formatted dummydb.dummy_table" ;
         PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();

    ##But I try to use this which is not working:

        String queryTable="dummydb.dummy_table"
        String sql1 = "describe formatted ?" ;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pstmt.setString(1, queryTable);
        ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Error
****org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'formatted' ''dummydb.dummy_table'' '' in describe statement****

Comment: This is expected behaviour, you can't pass the *table name* as a binding parameter. This is valid not only for `describe` but for all statements and not only for *table names* but also for *column names* too. Only the *values* can be parametrized. In this case you must concatenate the statement if you want to have a dynamic behaviour or use some dictionary table similar to `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` in Oracle (not sure whats the name in Hive).

Comment: Thanks @MarmiteBomber for quick and good answer. can you please tell me how to solve sonar issue which gives because of this.(not parametrized.)

Comment: Sorry @Manish which *sonar issue* do you have?